# How to make Next.js be SEO friendly and support PWA offline mode at the same time?

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

We have a Next.js application that supports SSR for SEO purposes.
This means that when you access any page, only the essential code necessary for that specific page is downloaded, resulting in minimal code retrieval. However, we also require PWA support, including installation and offline functionality, to ensure our app can operate without an internet connection.

The challenge we're facing is the inability to cache the entire application. The next-pwa plugin only caches files that are downloaded when visiting a page.

How to make Nextjs be SEO friendly and support PWA offline mode at the same time?